# What is Qt's equivalent to Python's range() function, returning a QList<int>?

Tags: python, qt, integer, range, qlist

If there is no equivalent function; is it possible to cleanly generate a `QList<int>` of `(1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... )` with one line of code, avoiding a `for loop` or having to write my own function?

Comment: No. Just pure Qt. I only referenced python as I am familiar with the function (Which apparently and unsurprisingly exists in a slew of different languages, such as ruby, postgres, etc)

Comment: @Akiva, have a look on my edit of the answer below.

Comment: I gave you a thumbs up, but your answer requires me to write my own function, which my question explicitly states that I am trying to avoid. Sorry :-)

Comment: @Akiva I don't see how this can be a problem. Could you explain why you cannot add a two-line function? This two commands is the best you will get without adding additional dependencies. Qt can do a lot for you but those guys will not add every functionality that any user might need into their library as a separate method.

Comment: Understood, but sometimes these things do exist, and were just not privy to them. Sorry again :-) But here; i'll make it up to you~

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the particularities of Qt containers, but in the STL you could do something like:

`std::vector<int> v(n);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 1);`

Or, if not using C++11, `std::generate_n(v.begin(), v.end(), my_iota(1));` where my_iota is a functor written by you that simply returns n++, with the initial value of n provided in the ctor.

<strike>If Qt containers provide iterators that comply with the STL OutputIterator concept you should be OK using std::generate or std::iota.</strike>

---

Qt containers (QList and QVector) provide STL compatible iterators that can utilize this functionality:

```
#include <QDebug>
#include <QVector>
#include <numeric>

inline QVector<int> range(int start, int end)
{
    QVector<int> l(end-start+1);
    std::iota(l.begin(), l.end(), start);
    return l;
}

int main()
{
    qDebug() << range(-3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
QVector(-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4)
```